# Вместе с ответом сервера приходит html-страница

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

При отправке post-запроса на сервер через ajax, в ответ приходит результат, после которого идет html-страница. Нужен только результат. Многое перепробовал - не выходит.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       cache: false,
       data:  {date: this.value},
            success: function(res){
                alert(res.result); //undefined
                alert(res.result); //{"result":"success"}<!DOCTYPE ...
            }
});
```

PHP-код:

```
if(isset($_POST["date"]) && !empty($_POST["date"])){
    echo json_encode(array("result" => "success"));
}
```

Comment: Первый очевидный вариант: `echo json_encode(array("result" => "success")); die();`. А под каким фреймворком вы работаете.

Comment: Фреймворк - CodeIgniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST["date"]) && !empty($_POST["date"])){
    echo json_encode(array("result" => "success"));
}
```

*Что идет после этого? Может быть дальше в коде встречается тот злосчастный echo который выводит страницу? - Используйте return, что бы прекратить выполнение скрипта.*

```
if(isset($_POST["date"]) && !empty($_POST["date"])){
        echo json_encode(array("result" => "success"));
        return ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

в ajax еще следует указать dataType: 'json'.
после echo json_encode(array("result" => "success"));
сделайте return; или die();

как вариант, возможно, вам в ответ приходит какой нибудь exception? и поэтому html страница?

Comment: Не забудем ещё и `header('Content-Type: application/json');` ;)

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/json') это не обязательно